# I have 2 monitors but the colours are different, why is this?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

The monitors i have are the exact same, the only thing different is one has a HDMI cable and the other a displayport cable. I went to search on the internet but I don't think that could be the problem. 
I also checked the settings on my computer and monitors but those are the same for both.

Comment: Manufacturing differences, variance in components, settings, user configuration, default calibration, connection type, etc... there are a host of possibilities. Just because 2 monitors are the same, doesn't mean they display the same, the most common issue is calibration, you may need to set them to look like each other in their menus, not set to the same empirical values

Comment: @acejavelin, consider posting an answer.  This may not be as common knowledge as you think.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is quite normal... Although *most* quality monitors that are "identical" often have a very similar display, that isn't always the case.

Manufacturing differences, variance in components, settings, user configuration, default calibration, connection type, etc... there are a host of possibilities. Just because 2 monitors are the same, doesn't mean they display the same, the most common issue is calibration, you may need to set them to look like each other in their menus, not set to the same empirical values.

Comment: You may also want to invest in a hardware color calibrator.